# Subtracting a color by 20 to get a darker color for an image

Tags: python

```
from images import Image
def main():
    image=Image("smokey.gif")
    amount=40
    sharp=20
    newimage=detectedges(image,amount,sharp)
    newimage.draw()


def detectedges(image,amount,sharp):
    def average(triple):
        (r,g,b)=triple
        return(r+g+b)
    blackPixel=(0,0,0)
    whitePixel=(255,255,255)
    new=image.clone()
    for y in range(image.getHeight()-1):
        for x in range(1,image.getWidth()):
            oldPixel=image.getPixel(x,y)
            print(oldPixel)
            leftPixel=image.getPixel(x-1,y)
            bottomPixel=image.getPixel(x,y+1)
            oldLum=average(oldPixel)
            leftLum=average(leftPixel)
            bottomLum=average(bottomPixel)
            
            if abs(oldLum-leftLum)>amount or \
               abs(oldLum-bottomLum)>amount:
                
                if (oldPixel[0]-sharp<0):
                    oldPixel[0])=0
                elif (oldPixel[1]-sharp<0):
                    oldPixel[1]=0
                elif (oldPixel[2]-sharp<0):
                    oldPixel[2]=0
            image.setPixel(x,y,oldPixel)
```

I am trying to make it so when oldPixel is subtracted by sharp and the amount is below zero it will just change to zero. For example if I have oldPixel[2] which is the blue in (r,g,b) and subtract it by my sharp it will subtract 20 throught each pixel color in the blue category but for some reason if my sharp which is 20 is on a color blue that has a value of 14,so it would be 14-20 instead of it doing my elif statement which should make that answer which would be -6 turn to 0. But for some reason it takes that -4 and gives me an error. I have been trying to use absolute values to counter this but it doesn't have an affect on the problem. BTW here is the error TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment

Comment: If you convert your image to grayscale at the beginning, you can avoid all of those "average" operations.  You never actually subtract `sharp` from `oldPixel` here.

Comment: So, if the current pixel is either much brighter or much darker than pixels to the left or below, you want it made darker.  Right?

Comment: yes also I never used grayscale so im doing it this way

Comment: But The idea here is that i am taking oldpixel and subtracting it by sharp to change the color of the image

Comment: It's excellent advice to use greyscale - it'll be faster and simpler.

Comment: yea but I wasn't permitted to use grayscale for my program so I am trying to solve the problem this way

Comment: You are still missing `else oldPixel[XXX] -= sharp` three times.

Comment: I am confused by what your meaning for oldpixel-= sharp

Comment: do you mean I am missing more oldpixel-sharps three times

Comment: Which line of your code takes the result of subtracting `sharp` and uses it to change the value of a pixel?

Comment: You are CHECKING whether the oldPixel values would go negative, but you never CHANGE `oldPixel`.  The pixel you wrote out is the exact same as the pixel you read in.

Comment: It's silly to say you weren't "permitted to use grayscale".  That's exactly what your `average` function is doing -- it's a crude conversion to grayscale.  You don't have to use a grayscale image, but you can certainly change it to grayscale for your processing.

Comment: Let's say `oldPixel` is 100 and `sharp` is 20. Which line sets the resulting pixel to 80?

Comment: The code as shown doesn't execute, due to a syntax error. `oldPixel[0])=0` has an unmatched parenthesis. Please make sure the code you're showing is the same that's getting you the result you describe.